# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create this simple RNN architecture in Keras:

- Input layer of 24 input neurons
- Recurrent hidden layer of 4 hidden neurons
- Output layer of 4 output neurons

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN

#fix random seed
np.random.seed(7)

trainX = np.loadtxt('trainX.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
trainT = np.loadtxt('trainT.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)

print(trainX)
print(trainT)
print(trainX.shape[1])

HIDDEN_LAYERS = 4

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(output_dim=HIDDEN_LAYERS, input_dim=trainX.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(SimpleRNN(4, input_dim=trainX.shape[1], input_length=128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=4))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainT, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=128)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error on the line where I add a SimpleRNN layer:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Does anyone know what's going on? The value of trainX.shape[1] is 24

Answer (score 1):

you can add your `SimpleRNN` as first layer and after your first change your train data shape like this:

```
trainX=trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0],1,trainX.shape[1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(4,  input_shape=(trainX.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=HIDDEN_LAYERS))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=4))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
...
```

or add a Reshape layer **without reshaping `trainX`**, like this:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=HIDDEN_LAYERS, input_dim=trainX.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Reshape((1,4)))
model.add(SimpleRNN(4))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=4))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Will adding SimpleRNN as the first layer create the same architecture I want (an input layer that is not recurrent)

Comment: I found `trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))` instead of `trainX=trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0],1,trainX.shape[1])` worked for me